# Programmatically populating a `<select>` element, using PreactJS

Tags: javascript, preact

```
class MySelect extends Component {
    constructor(params, renderFunction, uniqueId) {
        super(params);
        this.params = {
            ...params,
        };
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.state = params.state; // not sure why I need this to avoid a null state?
        this.updateColours = this.updateColours.bind(this); 

        // I also tried to "dangerously set innerHTML" with this:
        // this.optionElems = '';
        // Object.keys(this.params.options).forEach(key => {
        //     this.optionElems += `<option key="${key}" value="${key}">${this.params.options[key]}</option>`;
        // });
    }
    ...

        render(params, state) {
        const { options } = this.params;
        return (
          <div className='my-select'>
            <select value='BAR' onChange={(event) => this.updateColours(event)} options={options} >
              <option value='FOO'>Foo</option>
              <option value='BAR'>Bar</option>
              {Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
                return <option key={key} value={key}>{options[key]}</option>;
              })}
            </select>
          </div>);
    }
```

It is being called in the main App like so:

```
const myObj = {
  ONE: 'First option',
  TWO: 'Second option',
}

...


<MySelect wrapper={this.wrapper} state={this.state} options={myObj} />
```

When renderer, am I expecting the select on the page to contain:

```
<select>
  <option value="FOO">Foo</option>
  <option value="BAR">Bar</option>
  <option value="ONE">First item</option>
  <option value="TWO">Second item</option>
</select>
```

But all I get is:

```
<select>
  <option value="FOO">Foo</option>
  <option value="BAR">Bar</option>
</select>
```

NOTE:

I also tried this (defining the options first..):

```
    render(params, state) {
        const { options } = this.params;
        const optionsItems = Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
            console.log('option: val, name', key, options[key]);
            return <option key={key} value={key}>{options[key]}</option>;
        });
        console.log('options, optionsItems', options, optionsItems);
        return (
          <div className='my-select'>
            <select value='BAR' onChange={(event) => this.updateColours(event)} options={options} >
              {optionsItems}
            </select>
          </div>);
    }
```

The `options`, `params`, `optionsItem` are not empty, and all log what I expect..

I've read various things to no avail:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361667/5479837
- http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/dropdown-with-react
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48007119/5479837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OK I got a solution..

Pretty obvious to most I guess:

#### You MUST use an array of objects in this format:

In my the script which calls my `<MySelect>` component, somewhere near the top;

```
const options = [
  { value: "ONE", name: 'First item' },
  { value: "TWO", name: 'Second item' },
];
```

And then in the render function of the `MySelect` component:

```
    render(params, state) {
        const optionsItems = this.params.options.map((data) => <option key={data.value} value={data.value}>{data.name}</option>);
        return (
          <div className='my-select'>
            <select onChange={(event) => this.updateColours(event)}>
              {optionsItems}
            </select>
          </div>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way also, It's practically the same thing but in case you have a complex html to render you could just try this

```
render(params, state) {
        return (
          <div className='my-select'>
            <select value='BAR' onChange={(event) => this.updateColours(event)}>
              {this.params.options.map((data) => <option key={data.id} value={data.id}>{data.name}</option>)}
            </select>
          </div>);
```

I find it neater not to complicate the render function