# react, I want to put the data I created in the select options

Tags: reactjs, django

console.log(test)

[image click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VycPx.png)

The picture shows django's data by using console.log(test) in react.

my code

```
<Select placeholder="Select a player" style={{ width:'150px' }}>
<Option>{test.name}/Option>
</Select>
```

What I want is to put the name of the test data in the select option.

How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to iterate through the options and pass them as children of Select tag, [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413053/how-to-use-an-array-as-option-for-react-select-component);
You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, something like this:

```
<select>
 {Data.map(option => <Option>{option.name} </Option>)}
</select>
```